# paging with LIMIT on two tables

Tags: c#, mysql, ajax, json, paging

I have two tables in my database one called `artist`, and the other `song`.

```
song   => id, name, artist_ref 
artist => id, name
```

I need to get results from song table with some conditions about the songs like the year, number of views ... etc. 
 
On the other hand, I need to fetch the results according to the artist , in every page there is up to 50 artist, everyone of them have up to 10 songs to display, the next page should display another 50 artists (if exists).

 I should do this on the best possible way to gain maximum performance. 

 
Iv'e tried to use `LIMIT startIndex, offset` but it will return 50 songs not 10 songs per artist.
I'm using mysqldatareader to get the results then translate it to JSON, so I can call the function using ajax.

 
I'll be appropriated if anyone could help . thank you

Comment: What did you try and what isn't working.

Comment: @Rawhi are you displaying data somewhere? Are going to loop through the results using either PHP or any other language or its only mysql?

Comment: Pagination like this is an anti pattern that should be avoided.  As startIndex increases it's scaning through from the start each time and then giving you the tail "offset" at the end.  If you have an indexed Id column it would be better to paginate saying where Id between X and X+pagesize, where the literal value of X increases by pagesize

Comment: In this way I can't fetch results from different places in the db ...